# Compare two commits using gitlab api and get response in `.diff` format

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to compare two commits in Gitlab and get the response in `.diff` format.

I tried the APIs listed in Gitlab doc https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits. But it only returns the diff in `JSON` format.

How can I get the data in the git diff format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was initially requested in [issue 23285](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/23285) five years ago (Oct. 2016):

> GitHub seems have undocumented ways to download the unified diff file before create a pull request, that is: by add "`.diff`" or "`.patch`" suffix when comparing two branches.
>
> But GitLab didn't have that feature yet.

That particular feature is requested in [issue 217206](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/217206).

[Issue 20688](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20688) suggests:

> The only possible workaround, I do right now is to get the data from compare API, and then use grep to get diff, and append all of them.